# USB Microphone or Software which eliminates background noise

Tags: microphone, software, microphone-positioning

I live in an apartment next to a main road. As a result there are a lot of vehicles passing every minute. This leads to a lot of background noise(not consistent background noise like ambulance siren, dogs barking, people talking etc.) in the videos I create.

Is there a way to eliminate these noise.

Thanks,

Comment: Check out izotope.com for RX 5 Audio Editor software.

Comment: SoundSoap if your on a Mac, you can get it in the Appstore

Answer (score 1):

Using a reflexion filter would cut down on the ambient noise quite a significant amount. The shield acts as a somewhat portable booth due to the foam that reflects/absorbs the sound, giving the quality of recording a more natural sound.

Another possibility to try and cut down on ambient noise is to insert a noise gate on the same channel as your microphone and set the threshold so that only your speaking/singing voice crosses said threshold.

Reflexion filter that is good quality and fair price: http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/ReflexionX?adpos=1o1&creative=54989966161&device=m&matchtype=&network=g&gclid=CPD609XR8MYCFZKGfgodt5QOUg

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to eliminate these noises.

One expensive option would be to build a recording booth in your apartment.

Ways to reduce this problem : speak close to the microphone, record at night when the ambient noise is at it's minimum.

Using a noise gate as suggested in a comment could reduce background noise between words or sentences but will have no effect for background noise present while you're speaking.

Comment: Noise gate is an easy way to eliminate background noise.

Comment: A noise gate would not reduce background noise which is present under someone speaking.